# What is the most effective way to obtain an array of Date objects between two dates in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

So I have two dates

```
date_start = Date("2014", "11", "1")
date_stop = Date("2014", "12", "25")
```

if I want an array of `Date` objects between these two dates, what would be the most efficient methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an interval of `1.day` between dates:

```
(date1..date2).to_a
```

For other intervals, you'll have to populate an array yourself.

```
interval = 2.days

[date1].tap do |arr|
  until (arr.last >= date2)
    new_date = arr.last + interval

    # case 1: if you want the array to end on date2:
    arr << [new_date, date2].min

    # case 2: if you want the array to be equally spaced:
    arr << new_date

    # case 3: if you want the array to be equally spaced,
    #         but values to be within date1 and date2:
    if (new_date <= date2)
      arr << new_date
    else
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Normally you can use the `step` method on a range to specify the interval; but not in this case. The following, for example, doesn't work as you expect it to:

```
(date1..date2).step(2.days).to_a # outputs: [date1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Humza has said, you should use the [Ranges](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html) to solve your problem. You'll be able to:

- include or exclude the last value by using `..` or `...`
- define the step you want with `.step(YOUR_STEP)`

There is an example :

```rb
require 'date'

date_start = Date.new(2014, 11, 1)
date_stop  = Date.new(2014, 11, 6)

including_last_date = (date_start..date_stop).step(5).to_a
excluding_last_date = (date_start...date_stop).step(5).to_a

puts "INCLUDING : #{including_last_date.map(&:to_s)}" # INCLUDING : ["2014-11-01", "2014-11-06"]
puts "EXCLUDING : #{excluding_last_date.map(&:to_s)}" # EXCLUDING : ["2014-11-01"]
```

I hope this helps!